# Ambiguity of de-mangled C++ symbols

Tags: c++, gcc, demangler

```
_ZNSaIwEC1Ev
_ZNSaIwEC2Ev
```

These two C++ symbols differ but are demangled (using C++filt or similar utility) into the same form:

```
std::allocator<wchar_t>::allocator()
std::allocator<wchar_t>::allocator()
```

Why so? Could it be a demangler's defect or what else?

Comment: Is it important for the inverse of the mangling function to be injective? I only see how it's important for the *mangling* function to be injective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

g++ uses the name mangling scheme (and other implementation details) specified by the [Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html).

In the section on [mangling of constructors and destructors](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-special-ctor-dtor), we see:

```
<ctor-dtor-name> ::= C1 # complete object constructor
                 ::= C2 # base object constructor
                 ::= C3 # complete object allocating constructor
                 ::= D0 # deleting destructor
                 ::= D1 # complete object destructor
                 ::= D2 # base object destructor
```

- The "complete object constructor" including `C1` is the ordinary constructor directly used by initializations.
- The "base object constructor" including `C2` is used by a derived class constructor to initialize its base class subobject. This can be different from a "complete" constructor when virtual inheritance is involved, because only complete constructors initialize virtual bases, and base constructors instead assume their virtual bases have already been initialized.
- The "complete object allocating constructor" including `C3` presumably includes a call to `operator new`. But as far as I know, g++ never actually uses this one.
- The "deleting destructor" including `D0` finishes with a call to the appropriate scalar `operator delete`. This is necessary to tie to a virtual destructor because the correct `operator delete` might be a static class member which the base class knows nothing about.
- The "complete object destructor" including `D1` is like the reverse of the `C1` constructor, and includes calls to destructors of virtual base classes.
- The "base object destructor" including `D2` is like the reverse of the `C2` constructor, and omits calls to destructors of virtual base classes.

So the `C1` and `C2` pieces of the mangled names you asked about imply information which is important to the C++ system and must be correctly linked individually. But that information is difficult to briefly explain in a pseudo-code declaration, so the demangling function just describes both symbols identically.

Though since `std::allocator<T>` normally does not have any virtual base classes, it's likely that the two symbols actually point at the same code address, but g++ just provides both linker symbols for consistency.

Comment: In my case they do not point to the same address, but the code is identical.